# Can I create a PayPal subscription using BlueSnap API?

Tags: api, paypal, bluesnap

I want to create a subscription using Paypal. I created the API call but I want my BlueSnap console to manage it. Is there a way? I don't want to use the retrieve call all the time...

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Take a look at this post that will help you craft a question more likely to get an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bluesnap has two ways of managing the PayPal subscription: one using PayPal's system, and one using BlueSnap's subscription manager . In both cases, you do not need to retrieve the subscription constantly to charge it, if you're using a standard subscription.

In order to know which subscription management you will use, you can contact BlueSnap and ask about your account configuration.

In order to use the API to create a subscription in PayPal, you can use the extended API or the payment API.

**Extended API**:

1) create a subscription SKU to use: https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-Extended/docs/create-product, https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-Extended/docs/create-sku.

2) Create shopping context with the SKU: https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-Extended/docs/create-shopping-context. Make sure you use the PayPal examples.

3) Use the created Token URL to send to the shopper to approve the purchase in PayPal.

**Payment API**:

1) Create the PayPal transaction: https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-XML/docs/create-paypal-transaction.

2) Use the created Token URL to send to the shopper to approve the purchase in PayPal.